# Spring Boot Rest API Deployed on Tomcat gives 404 but works Stand-alone all fine

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have been working on Spring Boot Rest API using MongoDB with embedded Tomcat for about a month now to build a REST API. Everything was working fine. I now want to deploy the API in a separate development environment so that anybody can access the API.

I followed the step mentioned at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

1. Change the packaging to war
2. Added this to my pom.xml provided for spring-boot-starter-tomcat
3. extends my application to SpringBootServletInitializer and overwrote the
   configure method.
4. my application.properties has this:
   spring.data.rest.base-path=/

After doing all these:
I tried accessing the URL localhost:8080/my-war-name/employees it gives me 404 error but if I run the same application as standalone like via main() or run as Spring Boot. I can access my API at localhost:8080/employees

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide the log output from tomcat during deployment? which tomcat version are you deploying to?

Comment: Hi, could you find a solution for this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried localhost:8080/employees ?

It depends what the app- context path, if you want localhost:8080/my-war-name/employees you can add

server.context-path=my-war-name to application.properties
[More on config](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties)

Comment: Yes I did try the localhost:8080/employees and it didn't work and also tried adding server.context-path=my-war-name to application.properties that didn't help either.