# spring boot application gives 404 on tomcat 8

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat8

I have a Spring boot application using maven that deploys fine on my system but when deployed on tomcat 8 in Ubuntu 14 using war file gives 404 page.

This is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.web</groupId>
<artifactId>WebProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>WebProject</name>
<description>Admin project page</description>


<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.M3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
    <start-class>com.web.WebProjectApplication</start-class>
</properties>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>ng-csv</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->
      <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>ui-grid</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>angular-sanitize</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>file-saver</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>angular-file-upload</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>angular-route-segment</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>angular-resource</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

      <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <!-- Serves *only* to filter the wro.xml so it can get an absolute
            path for the project -->
          <id>copy-resources</id>
          <phase>validate</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/wro</outputDirectory>
            <resources>
              <resource>
                <directory>src/main/wro</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
              </resource>
            </resources>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.6</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>generate-resources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
        <cssDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/classes/static/css</cssDestinationFolder>
        <jsDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/classes/static/js</jsDestinationFolder>
        <wroFile>${project.build.directory}/wro/wro.xml</wroFile>
        <extraConfigFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.properties</extraConfigFile>
        <contextFolder>${basedir}/src/main/wro</contextFolder>
      </configuration>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
          <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
          <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
          <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

WebProjectApplication class

```
public class WebProjectApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(WebProjectApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(WebProjectApplication.class, args);
}
```

On tomcat this is the context.xml

```
<Context>
<!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
<!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts --    >
<!--
<Manager pathname="" />
-->
```

And this is part of server.xml file

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

I have read and tried out fixes from several posts for this issue but it did not work. like [Spring Boot Rest API Deployed on Tomcat gives 404 but works Stand-alone all fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583567/spring-boot-rest-api-deployed-on-tomcat-gives-404-but-works-stand-alone-all-fine)

Comment: Deploying spring boot to tomcat is usually not what you want, as spring boot can embed either tomcat or jetty

Comment: I use mvn clean package to get a war file which i deploy on the tomcat's webapps folder, to run on my system I just use mvn spring-boot:run